# О сокращениях типа "т. д.", "т. п."

Tags: сокращения

Действительно ли в середине предложения сокращения типа "т. д.", "т. п." надо писать полностью?

Comment: А какие ещё сокращения этого типа имеются?

Comment: @shampar, ещё имеется etc.

Comment: Понял: их много. И все в середину хотят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот оно оно:

**[4.4.1. Самостоятельно употребляемые сокращения (и др., и пр., и т. п., и т. д., т. е.)](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html)**

> Употребляются в любом контексте, с любыми соседними словами, за одним
> исключением — не рекомендуется в изданиях, не относящихся к
> справочным, употреблять сокращения *и др., и пр., и т. п.* в середине
> фразы, если далее следует согласованное с сокращением слово. Напр.:

**Рекомендуется:**

> Н. И. Петров, В. Г. Николаев и другие ученые...
>
> Эти и тому подобные книги...

**Не рекомендуется:**

> Н. И. Петров, В. Г. Николаев и др. ученые...
>
> Эти и т. п. книги...

Мы в 70-х учили, что эти сокращения - вы конце ли, в серёдке ли - развёртываются в художественной литературе, как и всякая цифирь,

если только это не авторский "штришок".

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я не запомнил, что "если далее следует согласованное с сокращением слово". Не могли бы Вы указать название книги?

Comment: У меня ссылка кликабельна (4.4.1): https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html

Comment: Ссылка (4.4.1): https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html Она взята из учебника А. Э. Мильчина "Справочник издателя и автора".

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Впервые слышу о подобном "требовании". Сразу вспоминаются книги и статьи Джона Барта, где на каждой странице по "и т.д.", "и т.п." — и никаких проблем с ними в отечественных изданиях. Отчего вдруг нельзя сокращать-то? Аббревиатуры, значит, можно, названия профессий, месяцы и прочее тоже, а с "и т.д." проблемы? Глупости. Ваш текст, ваши правила. И в большинстве случаев полное написание "и так далее" выглядит избыточным, т.к. краткое написание прижилось и понятно каждому. Кстати, "т.к." —  тоже сокращение, схожее с "и т.д." и в конце предложений не бывает, а как раз в середине. Но это его существованию нисколько не мешает.

Comment: Я это читал то-ли на Грамоте.ру, то-ли на каком-то редакторском-корректорском сайте. Там же пишут, что т. о. и т. н. лучше вообще не сокращать.

Comment: @Рад "т.о." и "т.н."  — это не настолько распространённые сокращения, которые мне, например, в серьёзном тексте встречать не приходилось. Я, к слову, даже сперва задумался, что они значат. С "и т.д." история другая   — это то, что называется, и ежу понятно, форма устоявшаяся, в пояснениях не нуждающаяся, чтение не тормозящая. Но если для Вас так важно мнение с сайта, который точно не помните, то, конечно, пишите полными выражениями, но, полагаю, это нецелесообразно. И лично моё мнение, что "и т.д." со сменой поколений станет нормой, а полный вариант вымрет. Впрочем, это не предсказать, конечно